# How do I verify my firmware is legitimate?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I just bought a "new" Galaxy S7, but the box was already open when it arrived.

Condition of the phone was perfect, so I don't mind if it's used/refurbished. What I worry about is whether the device has a keylogger installed or some other malware.

It successfully accepted an over-the-air update. This gives it *some* credibility (I don't know how indicative this is, but I believe OTA updates are only offered to stock firmware).

Samsung KNOX is enabled, and hasn't complained yet.

I've rebooted into recovery, and see the following text:

```
Android Recovery
MMB29K.G930FXXU1BPHJ
samsung/heroltexx/herolte
6.0.1/MMB29K/G930FXXU1BPHJ
user/release-keys
```

Those are real build numbers for stock firmware I have been able to find online.

I've rebooted into ODIN mode, and see the following text:

```
ODIN MODE
Download speed: fast
Product name: SM-G930F
Current binary: Samsung official
System status: official
FAP lock: ON
Secure download: enabled
Warranty void: 0 (0x0000)
RP SWREV: B:1 K:0 S:0
```

The KNOX counter (warranty void) is still set to 0. This suggests further that it has not been tampered with.

Are the checks that I have performed already sufficient? There are some further checks I would like to know how to do:

I expect anybody can just type a build number in. I would like to compare the checksum of the firmware with the real build. I also would like to check if it has been signed with a Samsung certificate.

There are no custom User certificates in its security section. But I would appreciate some way to compare my System certificates to confirm they are genuine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, your firmware is original, because it

- Received OTA - most clinching reason ( see edit for details)
- Knox isn't tripped
- Firmware number matches

For Samsung phones, there is a handy app that provides a lot of information about the phone, including **Refurbishment Check**. It also shows if the device is **original**. It is [Phone INFO *Samsung*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo). App developer thread on XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49394347)

This question shows you to verify the checksum of OS. You could try that with the checksum available on OEM site or SamMobile [Is there a way to verify stock ROMs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49746)

**Edit**

Starting from Android 5.0 [Block based OTA](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/block.html), in which the device can get an OTA when the **entire** `/system` partition matches with that does on their servers. Concerns of OP in comments are addressed here- if the system is modified OTA would fail

> ....File OTA tolerates some changes to the partition, such as the addition of files that are not part of the source or target build. However, **block OTA does not tolerate additions to the partition**, so users will need to install a full OTA overwriting any system partition modifications) or flash a new system image to enable future OTAs

(Emphasis supplied)

Comment: Thanks; that gives me a bit more confidence. Is it possible for _other_ parts of the phone's preloaded software to be malicious? When I first used it, it opened to a first-time setup wizard. But maybe this was just a malicious app rather than the real wizard.

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to where I could lookup a legitimate checksum. But to compare it, I need to know also how to find the checksum of what's installed on my phone. I have the build number but I don't know the hash of its contents.

Comment: 1. Pre loaded software implies part of system- if the system is modified, then you won't get an OTA or have Knox intact 2. Why do you suspect *first time setup wizard* ? - it's normal for phones to have that 3. IMO, there isn't a way to verify the checksum on your phone, simply because the checksum corresponds to a file format like `tar/ zip` which is a compressed format and on your device it is unpacked and installed

Comment: The reason I am wary of the first-time setup wizard, is: the merchant could get the phone with stock firmware, complete first-time setup, install an app which is a _fake_ first-time setup, open it to enable all its privileges, and then sell the phone. There is a question though of "where would the app come from?"; you couldn't put it on the app store, so developer mode and "unknown sources" would need to be enabled (they weren't when I received the phone). Additionally, making a perfect fake would be hard. I suspect the Android SDK privileges it requires would not be available to developers.

Comment: I am not a developer so can't comment on developer privileges. The moment you install a fake **system** app, wouldn't the system change? It would and OTA would fail. So I don't think that's a concern