# Is it safe to use OTA update while rooted with TWRP

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, twrp, ota-update, unrooting

I have a Lenovo Tab 2 A7-10 F, in which I have installed TWRP and rooted with SuperSu. Recently it notified me of an OTA update:

> T2_A7_10F_S000057_160701_ROW

But I am not sure if I should install it or not. Is it safe to download and install this update in the aforementioned configuration or will it damage my device? And if I try to do this,  will it even install? Or should I try to find a flashable zip file???Please Help

Comment: If the update is 5.0 or later, it will not be updated because of block based authentication as explained here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159797/131553

Comment: My device is already on 5.0. It's just a more stable version.

Comment: If I just remove root and TWRP, Will I be able to receive the OTA????

Comment: No because `/system` is modified by root and will not pass checking

Comment: So...is there any way to get the update??

Comment: I don't know.. Please search on XDA or wait for an answer

Comment: You have to rewrite your system partition from scratch to get an OTA update to be installed. Alternatively,  a full OTA update or fastboot type ROM can help you out. But if you do that, you could lose root as well as modifications done in system partition (such as Xposed framework). I don't have that particular device, so that's all I can suggest.

Comment: I have its original ROM of a previous version, which I flashed using sp flash tool.So if I flash it again, Will I be able to get the update???