# Official firmware for Moto G 2014 XT1069

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, device-firmware, motorola-moto-g2, motorola

I've got one Moto G 2014 XT1069 (dual sim) device, that I might need to flash the factory image. The point is that I'm totally new to this, and although I have found many tutorials on the matter, I'm still a little preocupated with the "official firmware".

As I understood this "flash the factory image" process is analogous to picking one bootable media and reinstalling Windows/Linux on a PC.

Now, what makes me more worried is that I've been searching for this official firmware and all the ones I've found are available through non-official sources like Mega.

This makes me worried: isn't there a risk that someone has tempered the image with some spyware-like or virus-like software that might capture data from the device?

Since these images are made available by non-official people, it makes me very worried about the extent to which is safe to use them.

Is it safe to use those images? Can I obtain one from a official source?

Where can I find one image for this device? I accessed XDA and found [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/general/firmware-retbrxt10695-0-2lxb22-46-28-zip-t3031891). It is indeed PT-BR language, which is what I'm searching, but I'm in doubt if I can trust this image and if this is the right image.

Is this the right image and can I trust it? If not, how can I obtain the correct image from a trustworthy source?

As I said I'm **totally** new to this, so sorry if I said something silly.

Answer (score 1):

- To obtain original firmware -Sign in on Motorola / Lenovo (Motorola had been taken over by Lenovo) site with device details , creating an account and search for firmware

**Edit:** OP has confirmed that he is unable to locate on the Motorola forums as older devices firmware is apparently removed. It is suggested that he mail the OEM or in the OEM forums for `sha / md5` of the firmware and compare with that of XDA download as explained here [Is there a way to verify stock ROMs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49746/131553)

- XDA firmwares are *generally* legitimate, but best of course is to get it from OEM if you don't trust

  - Firmware is usually downloaded by folks and hosted on file sharing sites like Mega, since

a) They can't or may not be permitted to link to original source always

b) Firmware may not be available on original source as later versions may replace earlier OS versions

c) For easier sharing - practically all sites hosting firmware use such sites

Since you specifically drew attention that you are new to this, downloading correct firmware is the first step and following instructions given by OEM / sites like XDA *meticulously*

Comment: Thanks for the answer @beeshyams. I've tried looking for the firmware on Motorola and they have a small set of recovery images, but they are only for the very latest devices, so the dates are from september. Could I get the one I need by contacting them via email or something like that?

Comment: You can try but I doubt it. That's one of the reasons people host images on file sharing sites as mentioned in reason B) above. What you can do with better chances of succeeding is asking for the `sha / md5'  and compare with that of download from XDA. Will update answer